# What is the sentence pattern of "I think that she is intelligent"

Tags: sentence-patterns

I understand that the sentence "She is Intelligent" would be pattern SVC, but what is the pattern when the sentence is "I think that she is intelligent". Because both "think" and "is" are verbs, I am confused. Is there a sentence pattern with two verbs that are not next to each other? Would it just be ASVC?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This question is probably too basic for this site. It might be better addressed at ELL, if only there were some research shown. I suggest that you start [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=that+clauses).

Comment: @cascabel I'm sorry if I came across as irritable. I think this is reasonable question. I don't think OP's question is a language learner's one. I think it's a genuine syntax one, which might be interesting for people who don't have an 'in' for syntactic  stuff. Where else can they go? Anyway, I salute your 20 years of helping students. I'm getting on to three quarters of that. I hope I get there too. Best wishes.

Comment: Avoid using comments for a purpose other than improving the post they are attached to. For example, comments can be used to ask the author for clarification, point out problems, or suggest changes. A better place for debate or free-wheeling discussion is our [chat] (or, when one exists, the chatroom attached to the post itself). A better place to make statements or ask questions about site design or policy is at [meta].

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.